# Using LINQ to populate a collection from a property that has n elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
public class A
{
   public List<object> MyItems { get; set; }
   public Color Color { get; set; }
   public object MyItem { get set; }
}
```

Each instance of A can have *n* MyItems.

Given a list of A's, I need to filter them by color, and create a new list, in which a new instance of A is created for every element of the MyItems collection.

```
List<A> Aitems = originalItems.Where(b => b.color == color)
                              .Select(b=>
{
    A aItem = b;
    // Problem below. Is there a way to create more
    // aItems for every object in MyItems collection?
    b.MyItem = b.MyItems[0];
    return aItem;
}).ToList();
```

Is there a way to create more aItems for every object in MyItems collection using LINQ or should I use a standard foreach?

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear at the moment, not least because your class declaration is invalid. If you could give us a short but *complete* sample class, along with sample input data and what you want the output to be, that would really help.

Comment: Please describe *create more aItems for every object in MyItems*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var query = from b in originalItems
            where b.Color == color
            from item in b.MyItems
            select new A
            {
                MyItems = b.MyItems,
                Color = b.Color,
                MyItem = item,
            };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create new A for every item in `MyItems` of A objects with specific color, you could do it like this:

```
from a in originalItems
where a.color == color
from myItem in a.MyItems
select new A { /* not sure what you want here */ }
```

Comment: [@Jared](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2489643) The question specifically asks for a collection containing “a new instance of A for every element of the collection”.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of all MyItems from OriginalItems where it is the color you want:

```
var items = (from a in OriginalItems
              where a.Color == color
              from item in a.MyItems
              select item).ToList();
```